# Redis sentinel cluster with Sails JS hickup

Tags: node.js, redis, sails.js

I am using Redis sentinel listeners (three to be exact) to manage my redis failover/cluster which connects with Sails JS through io-redis package [npm io-redis](https://github.com/luin/ioredis).  The application uses redis as it's socket store. On the sails js side I am using this configuration

```
// sockets.js
module.exports = {
  adapter: 'socket.io-redis',
  host: '192.168.1.100',}

// session.js
 adapter: 'connect-redis',
  host: '192.168.1.100',
  port: 16380,

// and in bootstrap.js
var redis = new Redis({sentinels:[
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16380 },
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16381 },
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16382 }],
        name:'redis-cluster'}
  );
//   // var Redis = ioredis.createClient();
  sails.config.session.store.client = redis;
  sails.config.sockets.adapterOptions.pubClient = redis;
```

This configuration is for multi-server environment which is running behind nginx load balancer. I have managed to make a successful connection to redis, it works as expected when you have the main node which is running at `port 16380` is online. As soon as this main node is killed or stopped, my application crashes. From what I understand the io-redis should handle this on it's own. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a redis client using `ioredis` then pass it as pub/sub/adminPub/adminSub client

```
// sockets.js
const Redis = require("ioredis");
const options = {sentinels:[
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16380 },
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16381 },
        { host: '192.168.1.100', port: 16382 }],
        name:'redis-cluster'};
const _client = new Redis(options);
module.exports.sockets = {
  adapter: "@sailshq/socket.io-redis",
  pubClient: _client,
  subClient: _client.duplicate(),
  adminPubClient: _client.duplicate(),
  adminSubClient: _client.duplicate(),
```